# Not able to read from access table properly

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have encountering a very silly problem. The requirement is to stop the duplicate entry in access table. I am using Vb6. But each time I try I am encountering syntax error.

**My code**

My flexgrid is populated and refreshed. I am able to insert and select data in another table in same database. But this one is failing

```
sql_txt1 = "Select SL_No from SpAIReport where DOM ='" & Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy") & _
"'  and AC-REG ='" & msgDisFlex.TextMatrix(i, 4) & "' and Flt No = '" & msgDisFlex.TextMatrix(i, 6) & "'"
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(sql_txt1)
```

I am able to update this table, but multiple time same data are getting populated.

The access table structure with the entries are given below

```
Date_OF_Fly Flt No  GMT Weight  Airtime Station     DOM     Data_hrs                Filename
7/3/2000    11      03:45:01    5       01:23:40    XXX     01/25/2014 120:10:15    ABCD
```

Plus, after saving if I want to access it through recordset then it is showing `NULL`.

The code is:

```
sql_txt = "select * from SpAIReport where DOM='" & dateDailyReport & "'"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql_txt)
```

The `dateDailyReport` value is `01/25/2014`. This value is present in database. Still this query is not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to put 'Flt No' and 'AC-REG' in square brackets otherwise they look like two field names:

```
 "'  and [AC-REG] ='" & msgDisFlex.TextMatrix(i, 4) & "' and [Flt No] = '" &
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I had made the mistake in flt no : the space and AC-REG : the hiphen. After changing the names with underscore it worked properly...